# Minor WPF XAML Designer bug with StaticResourceExtension unable to convert

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-6.0, designer

I'm trying to set an app-wide margin using:

```
<Thickness x:Key="DefaultMargin">3</Thickness>
```

But then I wanted to use that number to set other things like corner radius, borders, etc, so I did this:

```
<sys:Double x:Key="Spacing">3</sys:Double>
```

Which works fine until I go back and set the margin:

```
<Thickness x:Key="DefaultMargin"
           Left="{StaticResource ResourceKey=Spacing}" />
```

This compiles and runs fine until the application stops and the **when intellisense reloads the XAML file**, it whines: `XDG0062 Object of type 'System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension' cannot be converted to type 'System.Double'.`

But then I just build, and it goes away. After several searches on this site and others, I've gone back to constant numbers for now, but I'd like to only make one change if possible. Any ideas?

**UPDATE 1**

Attempting to try to apply more context, here's screenshot of my `App.xaml`: (the second error is similar in a separate file, so maybe this is systemic?)

[image: App.xaml screenshot]

I'm not sure how to add more context without attaching the full source.

**UPDATE 2**

After loading the `App.xaml` and some dependencies into a new solution, I found that **one of my converters was the culprit** (below):

```
namespace Program.View.Converters
{
    [ValueConversion(typeof(string), typeof(string))]
    internal class RatioConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
    {
        private static RatioConverter _instance;

        public RatioConverter() { }

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            double size = System.Convert.ToDouble(value) * System.Convert.ToDouble(parameter, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            return size.ToString("G0", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            return _instance ?? (_instance = new RatioConverter());
        }
    }
}
```

Which is referenced several places, but in `App.xaml` here:

```
...
xmlns:con="clr-namespace:Program.View.Converters"
...

<Style x:Key="DefaultWindow"
       TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
    <Setter Property="Width"
            Value="800" />
    <Setter Property="Height"
            Value="200" />
    <Setter Property="ResizeMode"
            Value="NoResize" />
    <Setter Property="SizeToContent"
            Value="Height" />
    <Setter Property="MaxHeight"
            Value="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight}, Converter={con:RatioConverter}, ConverterParameter='0.9' }" />
</Style>
```

Still not sure what's wrong with it, but I bet the `throw new NotImplementedException();` was trippping the designer. After reloading the fresh solution, the problem has gone away. I cannot seem to reproduce this consistently...

Comment: A little more context is always a good thing. You may know that it matters where resources are defined. To know how it is used is also a valuable information. Anyway, if it compiles and behaves properly then there is no reason to avoid resources. If the warning goes away after a build then there is no problem. You can make a solution Clear + Rebuild. Also clearing the cache can help. The warning seems to be related to the XAML designer. But again, not enough information to help you.

Comment: @BionicCode added some more context per recommendation. Also, I used rebuild with no difference in behavior. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Again, there are no errors related to the resource definitions. It looks like your designer cache is corrupt. Test your resources in a fresh solution. If this still doesn't help try to delete the .vs folder in your solution folder root.

Comment: @BionicCode thanks for the discussion! Deleting .vs and refreshing didn't work, but thanks to the "fresh solution" suggestion, I homed in on the problem and updated the question.

Comment: Would you mind to complete your question and post the relevant context? It's not possible for someone who does not know your application and the actual context to understand what you are doing. For example, where and how do you use the converter? How does the resource relate to the converter? Please create a minimal example that reproduces the error.